# Why Do My Monitors Wake Up Immediately After Going to Sleep?

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend

My work machine runs Ubunutu 18.04. I'm trying to get my monitors to sleep and not having much luck.

I opened the Energy Saving module of System Settings and found the Screen Energy Saving was checked (even though my monitors don't sleep). I turned the Switch off after value down to 1 minute and waited. After a minute, the monitor displays the no signal warning and powers down to sleep mode. About 15 seconds later, with no discernable input, the main monitor wakes up followed by the secondary monitor maybe 5 seconds later. After the self restart, neither monitors will go to sleep again unless i manually reapply the setting. Rinse and repeat.

I'm a fairly experienced computer professional, but new to Ubuntu> i'd appreciate any ideas on how to debug and correct this somewhat annoying problem.

Comment: I found for me that skypeforlinux keeps annoying me for that..probably. Do you have it running?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue is related with monitor internal setting named **Input Control -> Auto-Switch Input** (or similar). This was my case. I just turned off autodetection for my HP Z24i G2 and set detection mode to HDMI only.